# Automatically populate geolocation field(s) when user updates address?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, geolocation

I will soon have a list of addresses that will be updated and maintained by various members in our organization. A program I am writing will need access to these addresses to compute the ones closest to a given location. To make this task easier I thought of adding a geolocation column or a latitude and longitude column that would get updated anytime a row's address is changed.

I could not find any information on doing this online, which is surprising because entering latitude and longitude is not exactly as user friendly as just modifying an address and having those fields auto-update. Any guidance on this issue would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create SharePoint Event Receiver that updates LAT/LON in ItemAdding/ItemUpdating event of SharePoint list item, or inject JavaScript to the Add/Edit form of the list that populates LAT/LON fields when user has filled the Address field and focus moves away from that field.

Use external service such as Bing Maps REST service to determine LAT/LON from the given address. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx)

To me, the list form modification seems perhaps bit better as you can do everything on client side without external Event Handler code.